Delivery option calculation rateslib [multiple questions]
I am using rateslib and I am trying to price the bond future TYZ4 on the 2024-09-23. I want to be able to price the delivery option of that bond future.
The way I am doing is as follow:
(1) perform PCA on the yields of the bonds in the basket.
(2) generate different yield scenarios at maturity using PC1 and PC2.
To generate the different yield scenarios I am using the implied vol of the option on TYZ4. Then I need to scale PC1, and PC2 accordingly when generating the different scenarios. If $\alpha_1, \alpha_2, \sigma$  is the explained variance of PC1 and PC2 and $\sigma$ is the implied vol then my scalings are: $\frac{\alpha_i}{\alpha_1 + \alpha_2} \times \sigma^2$.
[Q1]: When performing PCA on the bond basket I found that PC1 is a clear parallel shift of the yield curve while PC2 is a steepening. This seems correct. Though I found that the explained variance of PC1 is $0.998$ which basically says that PC2 explains almost no variance. Is that normal? My guess would be that since the bond in the basket are extremely similar in maturities then steepening can't happen too much and all the bonds moves together when rates changes. This then means that when I am generating all my scenarios I am basically just modelling parallel shift scenarios, is that a problem?
All the data needed to perform this analysis on the 2024-09-23 is here ( I define the clean price on 2024-09-23, the repo rate of the bonds, the conversion factors, the PCs, the explained variance of the PCs and the implied vol):
The price of the bond future on 09/23 was 114.75. I can now generate 1000 different scenarios and calculate the bond future price as well as the probability of delivery of each bond:
I then found that future_value / 1000 = 114.18 which is not a bad result since it's quite closed to what's been observed in the market. Yet I found that the probability of delivery of US91282CKW00 is 100%! which is definetely weird here. So I guess there is a problem in what I am doing but I don't know why.
A few guesses:

On BBG the implied vol is $6.46$. Since it's annualized and there is $99$ days between 2024-09-23 and the delivery date 2024-12-31. Then the implied vol I am using is: $\frac{6.46}{100} \cdot \sqrt{\frac{99}{365}}$. The problem is that this vol is the log-normal vol so I should probably use np.random.lognormal but then I get a future price of ~112 which is completely off.

If instead I put an implied vol of $0.5$ and generate $10000$ samples then I get a probability of 0.9992 for US91282CKW00 and 0.0008 for US91282CLJ89. I found it very weird that even using a high implied vol I get an almost 100% chance of delivery for US91282CKW00.


[Q2] What am I doing wrong here? Shouldn't the other bonds also have a probability of delivery?
Many thanks,

Why do all your bonds start on 23rd Sep 24? I assume that is "today", but that is not the correct specification of the given ISINs. This page (https://rateslib.readthedocs.io/en/latest/z_bondctd.html) starts all the bonds 18 months in advance so that it assumes that all bonds have a full initial coupon from some appropriate roll date. Historical stub periods and completed coupon periods are irrelevant. Only bonds with an active front stub period are mis-valued in that analysis. All of your bonds are likely misvalued.

@Attack68 Thanks for your comment. If I understand correctly you are saying that I can be in the middle of two coupon dates so using an effective date as of today doesn't take this into account right? So I need to put a stub period for the first coupon equal to next_coupon_date - 23rd of September?

If a bond starts 15-nov-2018 and ends 15-nov-2028, then its effective date should be 15-nov-2018. For the above documentation page I couldnt be bothered to lookup and apply all the bonds effective dates. I made the assumption that none of the bonds had stubs, and thus applied an effective date whose first coupons were in the past. For "today" as 24-sep-2024 this bond would need an effective date of 15-may-2024 or earlier to ensure that it correctly accounst for the last coupon date of the current period. You can correct this assumption by actually using the correct effective date for each bond

@Attack68 Yes I agree, thank you. I overlooked that. I changed the code and it changes the result slightly. Otherwise what do you think about the overall methodology and the results I get? (for example the fact that US91282CKW00 has an almost 100% chance of delivery?) I know it' a long question but I am just trying to understand what I am doing wrong here. Thanks in advance

I haven't looked in detail, but my instinct says you are doing something wrong, unless the volatility is low and the scenario analysis does not create enough variation by settlement that actually the CTD has little chance of changing. Try replicating your argument with the data from that page linked to. At the level of rates given in that page there are quite a few different CTD changes for not that different levels in rates. If you method doesn't work there, further evidence it is flawed.

Delivery should be be first delivery atm as far as I am aware.

@Attack68 I did the same analysis and I get that there's a CTD change only after +40bps of parallel shock. 40bps is basically PC1. The problem is that with the implied vol I am using this never get realized. So i am wondering what implied vol I should be using and how to use it. I was following Helin post here: https://quant.stackexchange.com/questions/76833/calculating-dv01-for-treasury-futures-with-ctd-switch-risk/76864#76864 which says to use the implied vol on bond future options.

@user68819 i don't understand. You mean delivery date should be one week before last date?

No the optimal delivery date is the first delivery, 02/12/2024, as carry is negative.

@user68819 oh yes right! I get 114.7489 now. Which is really good. Yet I don;t know if it's not just luck now since I have some doubts in the way i am using the implied vol...
